# Prolog insert into a list

Tags: prolog

I would advice about this exercise:

> Write a method insert, which has 3 parameters, the first an ordered
>   list, the second an int and the third an ordered list without repeated
>   values equal as the first one but containing the second parameter.

Example:

```
> insert([5, 6, 30, 60, 90], 40, L)
L = [5, 6, 30, 40, 60, 90]

> insert([5, 6, 30, 60, 90], 30, L)
L = [5, 6, 30, 60, 90]
```

I would do:

```
insert([],_,[_]).

insert([H],_,Result) :-
Result < H,
insert([],[],[Result|H]).
insert([H],_,Result) :-
Result > H,
insert([],[],[H|Result]).

insert([H,Y|Rest], _, Result):-
_ < Y,
insert([X|Rest], [], Result).
insert([H,Y|Rest], _, Result):-
_ > Y,
insert([Y|Rest], [], Result).
```

But I think base case when there is only one element is redundant and not needed because of we have the general recursive case and the empty list one. I need some suggest to improve or better explanations to polish the code.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: You are improperly using an anonymous variable (`_`) where you should be using a real named variable. Anonymous variables are used when you aren't concerned about how it's bound. Use `insert([], X, [X])` instead, as well as `insert([H,Y|Rest], X, Result):-
X < Y, ...` etc.

Comment: Thank you lurker for your explanation, now I realize _ has its own meaning and when I need to bound variables with values I need to use a string starting with capitalized letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way :

```
% First element of the list is smaller than V
% we keep on wth the rest of the list
insert([H | T], V, [H|V1]) :-
    H < V, !, % remove choice points
    insert(T, V, V1).

% First element of the list is equal than V
% insert([V | T] , V, [V|T]).
% corrected after **enoy** remark
insert([V | T] , V, [V|T]):- !.

% First element of the list is greater than V, found the place of V
insert([H | T] , V, [V,H|T]).

% insert V in an empty list (V is greater than all elements of the list)
insert([], V, [V]).
```

with the same results as the **Users9213** answer.

**EDIT** A way to avoid cut is

```
% First element of the list is smaller than V
% we keep on with the rest of the list
insert([H | T], V, [H|V1]) :-
    H < V,
    insert(T, V, V1).

% First element of the list is equal than V
insert([V | T] , V, [V|T]).

% First element of the list is greater than V, found the place of V
insert([H | T] , V, [V,H|T]):-
    H > V.

% insert V in an empty list (V is greater than all elements of the list)
insert([], V, [V]).
```

Comment: Thank you joel76 for taking care and answer clearly and with comments. Just one suggestion, if you query: insert([1],1,L). as a result will output both statements: L = [1]; L = [1,1] just use cut operator and avoids the second answer. So that line is insert([V|T], V, [V|T]) :- ! .

Comment: @enoy and of course author of answer, why is there cut? it is not necessary (well it is necessary here but not necessary in general) and it is also wrong: can you see how?

Answer (score 2):

Try with compare:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

insert([], X, [X]).
insert([X|Xs], New, Ys) :-
    zcompare(Order, X, New),
    insert(Order, X, New, Xs, Ys).

insert(>, X, New, Xs, [New,X|Xs]).
insert(=, X, _, Xs, [X|Xs]).
insert(<, X, New, Xs, [X|Ys]) :-
    insert(Xs, New, Ys).
```

but maybe you need explanation? It is strange, because you could also just read documentation as I did and find why this is good enough implementation, but of course maybe it is good to explain more, just in case.

```
insert([], X, [X]).
```

> When first argument is empty list, second argument is the only element of the result list.

```
insert([X|Xs], New, Ys) :-
    zcompare(Order, X, New), ...
```

> When first argument is list with at least one element, take head element and compare it to New element. After `compare` or `zcompare` first argument Order is either `>` or `=` or `<` (but what do these mean? maybe guess or maybe even read documentation if it is not too much work).

```
insert(Order, X, New, Xs, Ys).
```

> After comparing take the Order and the rest of the variables and....

```
insert(>, X, New, Xs, [New,X|Xs]).
```

> Element at head of list is larger than New element. This means that result list should be New element followed by head followed by rest of list.

```
insert(=, X, _, Xs, [X|Xs]).
```

> Element at head of list is exactly the same as New element. We are done, no need to insert anything just keep original list as result.

```
insert(<, X, New, Xs, [X|Ys]) :-
    insert(Xs, New, Ys).
```

> Element at head of list is smaller than New element: New element must come after this element in result. So we put current element back in list and search for place of New element in rest of list.

So much text, but is it now easier to understand what code says? Maybe or maybe not?

there

```
?- insert([5, 6, 30, 60, 90], 40, L).
L = [5, 6, 30, 40, 60, 90].

?- insert([5, 6, 30, 60, 90], 6, L).
L = [5, 6, 30, 60, 90].

?- insert([5, 6, 30, 60, 90], 100, L).
L = [5, 6, 30, 60, 90, 100].

?- insert([5, 6, 30, 60, 90], 0, L).
L = [0, 5, 6, 30, 60, 90].
```

but there are more interesting things to do with this solution because it uses a predicate like `zcompare/3` which looks a bit like `compare/3` but it knows integer constraints so it is possible to query:

> What integers can be inserted in list [1,3,4]?

```
?- insert([1,3,4], X, R).
R = [X, 1, 3, 4],
X in inf..0 ;
X = 1,
R = [1, 3, 4] ;
X = 2,
R = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
X = 3,
R = [1, 3, 4] ;
X = 4,
R = [1, 3, 4] ;
R = [1, 3, 4, X],
X in 5..sup.
```

So you can insert any integer < 1 at front, or you can "insert" 1 that was there, or you can insert 2 between 1 and 3, or you can "insert" 3 or 4, or you can insert 5 or anything larger at the end of list.